# How to delete the special round sign in a hindi letter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to place a hindi character in some div element.
But the special round sign is not needed there.

Here how these letters looks like.

```
ा
ी
ि
ो
ौ
```

I need exactly the standalone text character as the real solution but not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Hindi font to show the letter WITH diacritic :

CSS found here [wiktionary.org ा](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%BE)

```css
.Deva {
  font-family: 'Adobe Devanagari', 'Noto Serif Devanagari', Utsaah, 'Devanagari MT', Raghu, Gargi, JanaSanskrit, JanaHindi, Siddhanta, Akshar, sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<strong class="Deva" lang="mul">ा  ी  ि  ो  ौ</strong>
```

Result in Chrome on Mac

[image]

Result on  Chrome Win10 after installing devanagari-mt-2.ttf

[image]

Result in Carsten's Chrome on Windows 10

[image: Chrome on Windows 10]

Result in KiranVJ's Chrome 107 Win 10 and Adobe

[image]

Comment: I just don't need diacritics but only letter.

Comment: Which is what I did. You need the correct font for the diacritics to work. Run the snippet!

Comment: it's not working  [link](https://snipboard.io/68uX9d.jpg)

Comment: See my image - works in Chrome on Mac for sure

Comment: I'm happy for you but it's not working in my chrome browser on windows 7 OS.
if you could send your Mac to me  it would be great

Comment: but still thank you for your time!

Comment: Its working for me in Win10 Chrome 107. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtjqw.png)

Comment: on adobe site works for me too [adobe font](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/adobe-devanagari#fonts-section)

but there the font is different [screen] (https://snipboard.io/R7Ioiv.jpg)

and but for me it's not working on my site [screen](https://snipboard.io/MeF3jm.jpg)

Comment: @drewango You can and need to download a ttf - for example from here: https://en.maisfontes.com/devanagari-mt-2.font

Comment: मदद के लिए बहुत धन्यवाद

Comment: आपका स्वागत है .